# Getting .live or .delegate or livequery plugin to keep cart alive

Tags: php, jquery

I have this ajax-loaded #container and I'm trying to get it to play nice with some of my plugins. So far I managed to get scrollTo and a lightbox working inside this "container of death" using jquery.live but no luck with my fancy "add to cart" buttons. I've been playing around with .delegate, the livequery plugin, etc., for a few days now but I'm really not advanced enough to figure out what goes where. (I have a pretty shallow understanding of what I'm doing.)

Here's my shopping cart plugin, it's fairly small and straightforward. Can you give suggestions on what (.live, .delegate, or .livequery, or perhaps something else entirely) should be inserted where?

(Note: shopme p = the add to cart buttons, which need to be inserted inside the ajax-loaded "container of death." The rest of the cart exists outside said container and works fine since it's not ajax'ed in.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.wooo').bloooming_shop();

$('body').append('<div id="panel"><div id="panelcontent"></div><div class="panelbutton" id="hidepanel" style="display: none;"><a><font class="cartfont2">hide cart</font></a></div></div><div id="showpanel" class="panelbutton" style="display: visible;"><a><font class="cartfont">shopping cart</font></a></div><div id="btntarget"></div>');
$('#panelcontent').hide();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/wooo/cart.php",
    async: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
        $('#panelcontent').html(html);
    }
});



$(".panelbutton").click(function(){
    $("#panel").animate({
        height: "200px"
    }, "fast",function(){
        $('#panelcontent').show();
    });
    $("#hidepanel").fadeIn();
    $("#showpanel").fadeOut();

}); 

  $("#hidepanel").click(function(){
    $("#panel").animate({
        height: "0px"
    }, "fast", function(){ 
        $("#showpanel").fadeIn();
        $('#panelcontent').hide();
    });

    $("#hidepanel").fadeOut();
   });  


   // START 'ADD TO CART' BUTTONS

$('.shopme p').click(function(){

    var pid = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('body').prepend('<div class="shadow" id="'+$(this).attr('rel')+'_shadow"></div>');

    var shadow = $('#'+pid+'_shadow');

        shadow.width($(this).parent().css('width')).height($(this).parent().css('height')).css('top', $(this).parent().offset().top).css('left', $(this).parent().offset().left).css('opacity', 0.5).show();
     shadow.css('position', 'absolute');

     shadow.animate( {
            width: $('#btntarget').innerWidth(), 
            height: $('#btntarget').innerHeight(), 
            top: $('#btntarget').offset().top, 
            left: $('#btntarget').offset().left 
            }, { 
            duration: 2000 
            } )
        .animate({ 
            opacity: 0 
        },
        { 
        duration: 700,
        complete: function(){

        shadow.remove();

    }

    });

    var option = $('#'+pid+' .woooptions').val();

    var formData = 'pid=' + pid + '&option=' + option; 

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/wooo/cart.php',
        data : formData,
        success : function (html) {
            $('#panelcontent').html(html);
        }
    });


}); 


$('.removeitem').live('click', function() { // .LIVE is used here   
    rid = $(this).attr('id');
    rop = $(this).attr('rel');

    var remData = 'remove=' + rid + '&rop=' + rop; 

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/wooo/cart.php',
        data : remData,
        success : function (html) {
            $('#panelcontent').html(html);
        //  alert('thx');
        }
    });

});




}); // document

function checkOut(){
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "/wooo/cart.php",
          type: "POST",
        data : "destroysession=true",
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if(data){
                window.location.href=jQuery('a.checkout').attr("data-href");
            }else{
                console.log("There is no data!")
            }
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("AJAX ERROR: "+errorThrown)
          }
        });
}

/** replace ******/

jQuery.fn.bloooming_shop = function(){

    this.each(function(){

        var elem = $(this);

        var cl = 'bt1';
        var id = $(this).html();
        var opt = $(this).attr('options');
        var text = $(this).attr('text');
        var price = $(this).attr('price');
    //  alert(price);

        if (text == undefined) {
            text = 'add to cart';
        }

        if (opt == 'true' && price != 'true' ) {
            cl = 'bt3';
        }

        if (price == 'true' && opt == 'true') {
            cl = 'bt4';
        }

        if (price == 'true' && opt != 'true') {
            cl = 'bt2';
        }

        elem.removeClass('wooo');
        elem.addClass('shopme');
        elem.addClass(cl);
        elem.attr('id','pid'+id);
        elem.html('<p rel="pid'+id+'" class="'+cl+'">'+ text +'</p>');

        // get product data
        if (price == 'true' || opt == 'true') {

            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : '/wooo/functions.php?mode=p_data&id='+id+'&opt='+opt+'&price='+price,
                success : function (html) {

                    elem.append(html);

                    if (jQuery().sSelect) {
                            elem.children('.woooptions').sSelect();
                     } 

                    // change price
                    $('.woooptions').change(function(){
                        var selid = $(this).attr('id');
                        var rel = $('#'+selid+' option:selected').attr('rel');

                        if (rel != undefined) {
                              $(this).parent().children('.woooprice').html(rel);
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }

    });

return false;

};
```

How do I keep this plugin alive, even within ajax'ed-in #container? I really just need the 'add to cart' buttons (shopme p) to be in said container div. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, put `$.live()` out of your mind; it's hideously inefficient and "long deprecated". `$.delegate()` is too, I believe. Use `$.on()` if you need to hook into an event for an element.

Comment: *The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see **`.bind()`, `.delegate()`, and `.live()`**.* - [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/) That list I highlighted are deprecated or there are plans to do so.

Comment: .on does not work in all methods where only live does work.  Deprecated or not there is no other way.  yes, they want you to remove it from most things because on works in... 90% of the situations, however there are still times that only live will do the job, YES it comes at a premium, but if that's what you must do.

Comment: @Iscariot - Hey, I understand; it took me a while to "get" `$.on()`. I couldn't even get it to work the first few times I used it. That quote above is from the jQuery API; I didn't make that up. I can't think of the last time I was tempted to use `$.live()`, once I figured `$.on()` out.

Answer (score -1):

```
.live("click", function(){
```

instead of just click.

Comment: No no no, [`$.live()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/). Here thyre be tygers.

Comment: In some cases its the only way to do something.  If you are introducing new content that is being loaded via Ajax then you have to reload the dom in order to have access to the new content.  I could be wrong and if I am I would love to know how to and I will make sure thats what I use from now on.

Comment: `$.live()` is a reactive way of handling events; `$.on()` is a proactive, more organized method of handling events. `$.live()` delegates everything to `document`, which is hugely inefficient. `$.on()` says "identify what will occur before hand and *properly prepare to accept it*". `$.live()` is messy and disorganized. `$.on()` is more difficult but the far-superior approach.

Comment: I agree, but that still does not solve the issue I brought up.  On is 100% a much better function, however I have never been able to do what I mentioned previously with on.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; do you have a demo of that use case?

Comment: What are you not getting?  I get that you read that live is deprecated.  However, if you use say load or a JSON request to get information, you then build and display this information. To now have a click function work for the information that was loaded AFTER the page was. You have to use live.   If there is another way, I'd like to see it.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of that demonstration Iscariot? Because .on is supposed to be able to handle what bind, delegate and live does.

Comment: Hmm. If `$.live()` were the only way to do that, do you think they would be deprecating it? Something that integral to how jQuery adds value? For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/MCRF9/ You could also use [`documentFragment`](http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#6). Or just put the `click` handler into a function and reuse the reference when you get the content to add the `click` handler after the content has returned success and before you append it. I don't see the issue.

Comment: I tried live click function but something more is needed to keep those 'add to cart' buttons alive. (I also tried .on for keeping scrollTo alive, and .delegate, but only .live ended up working.)